# How to align Gridview / Listbox Items to centre alignment in UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

i want to list Gridview/listbox 3 items to each row...suppose last row have one item only, then i need to display that item to second column. and suppose i have 2 items in last row, then i need to display first item to  between 1 st and 2nd column and 2nditem to 2nd and 3rd column.

suppose if i have 7 items, in this scenario i want like this

[image: 7 list in this scenario]

suppose if i have 8 items, in this scenario i want like this

[image: 8 list in this scenario]

Comment: Any updates for this? If my reply makes sense, please consider accepting it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The GridView and ListBox are using different panels to order their child items.The default item panel for **GridView** is `ItemsWrapGrid` and **ListBox** uses `VirtualizingStackPanel`. A panel is an object that provides a layout behavior for child elements it contains when the Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML) layout system runs and your app UI is rendered.

If you want to order the items with different rules, you might need to custom your own panel. You can define custom panels for XAML layout by deriving a custom class from the **Panel** class. You provide behavior for your panel by overriding the `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`, supplying logic that measures and arranges the child elements.

Here is a document about the detailed information about how to custom a panel: [XAML custom panels overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/custom-panels-overview). And you could get an example about the detailed steps here: [BoxPanel, an example custom panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/boxpanel-example-custom-panel).